# принцип работы Monitor.Pulse/Wait

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Пишу программу. Есть Queue _readedBlocks.
С ней работают три функции:

1. Конструктор. При создании класса инициализируется очередь.
2. EnqueueReaded
3. DequeueReaded

   ```
   public static void EnqueueReaded(Block block)
   {
       lock (_readedBlocks)
       {
           _readedBlocks.Enqueue(block);
           Monitor.Pulse(_readedBlocks);
       }
   }

   public static Block DequeueReaded()
   {
       lock (_readedBlocks)
       {
           if (!_readedBlocks.Any())
           {
               if (endOfRead)
                   return null;

               Monitor.Wait(_readedBlocks);
           }

           return _readedBlocks.Dequeue();
       }
   }
   ```

Больше нигде в коде ***_readedBlocks*** никак не используется. У меня один поток заполняет ***_readedBlocks*** и два потока его опустошают. В какой то момент у меня вылетает исключение "Очередь пуста". Что я делаю не так? По сути же если очередь пуста, поток становится в ожидание. Как только в очередь добавляется элемент, первый из ждущих получает пульс и работает с его добычей, в то время, как второй должен сидеть и ждать, пока заполняющий поток не подтянет еще элементов. Что не тка в этой логике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кейс:

1. Поток чтения 1 ушел в Wait
2. Поток записи посылает Pulse и освобождает блокировку
3. Поток чтения 2 входит внутрь секции и читает (MSDN пишет, что Pulse не гарантирует получения доступа к секции первым именно потока получившего Pulse)
4. Поток чтения 2 покидает секцию
5. Поток чтения 1 получает доступ, но очередь уже пуста

Для наглядности я модифицировал твой пример:

```
lock (_readedBlocks)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    if (!_readedBlocks.Any())
    {
        if (endOfRead)
            return null;
        Console.WriteLine($"Wait: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        Monitor.Wait(_readedBlocks);
        Console.WriteLine($"Release: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Dequeue: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); 
    return _readedBlocks.Dequeue();
}
```

Перед exception получился вот такой output:

```
Wait: 4
Pulse: 3
Enter: 5
Dequeue: 5
Release: 4
Dequeue: 4
```

Имхо, в твоем случае, самой лайтовой правкой будет обернуть Wait как-нибудь вот так:

```
 do {
     Monitor.Wait(_readedBlocks);
 } while (!_readedBlocks.Any());
```

Comment: То есть при Pulse поток чтения 2 пролетает сразу на чтение ибо очередь "не пустая",  и при этом же снимается блокировка с Wait для потока чтения 1, который долетает до чтения уже пустой очереди?

Comment: угу, поток чтения 2 захватывает секцию и читает, а поток чтения 1 получил пульс и готовится к захвату как только освободится секция. Цитата msdn: При получении импульса ожидающий поток перемещается в очередь готовности. Когда поток, вызвавший метод Pulse освобождает блокировку, следующий поток в очереди готовности (который не обязательно является потоком, получившим импульс) получает блокировку.

Comment: спасибо) как раз как только написал вопрос к этому и пришел. решил не удалять, чтоб проверить правильность рассуждений